# How to count rows and sum columns when I group by some columns?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

It seems easy, but it's not. Please read the query:

```
SELECT 
    b.d_comp, b.fk_frnc, 
    CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(b.d_comp, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
        " - ", f.nome
    ) AS alias, 
    FORMAT(SUM(b.vlr), 2, 'de_DE') AS vlr, 
    
    # ACRÉSCIMO DE SOMAS, CASO TOTAL POR LOTE ESTEJA HABILITADO #
    CONCAT(
        '<span class="fw-bldr">Fêmeas</span>:<br>Quantidade | Peso<br>Adultas:',
        # QTD #
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE 
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc AND
                b2.novilho IS FALSE
        ),
        ' | ',
        # PESO #
        (
            SELECT SUM(b2.peso) 
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE 
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc AND
                b2.novilho IS FALSE
        ),
        '<br>Novilhas: ',
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc AND
                b2.novilho IS TRUE
        ),
        ' | ',
        (
            SELECT SUM(b2.peso)
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc AND
                b2.novilho IS TRUE
        ),
        '<br>Total: ',
        (   
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc
        ),
        ' | ',
        (
            SELECT SUM(b2.peso)
            FROM bois AS b2
            WHERE
                b2.genero = 'F' AND
                b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND
                b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc
        )
    ) AS total_lote
FROM 
    bois AS b INNER JOIN 
    fornecedores AS f 
WHERE 
    b.fk_frnc = f.id
GROUP BY b.d_comp, b.fk_frnc
```

My problem is collect the COUNT of rows and SUM of weight (peso). Return of query show the alias total_lote with NULL for any row.

I edited the code. Sorry. This is the correct query. It returns null to alias *total_lote*.

Thanks for all.

Comment: If you want to get an answer I suggest you add the CREATE TABLE statements, some sample data as insert statements and/or markdown tables and your expected output as another markdown table. Your current approach is most definitely sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the six separate sub-queries you can use one with conditional aggregation and put it in as a derived table -

```sql
SELECT
    d_comp,
    fk_frnc,
    SUM(IF(novilho IS FALSE, 1, 0)) AS col1,
    SUM(IF(novilho IS FALSE, peso, 0)) AS col2,
    SUM(IF(novilho IS TRUE, 1, 0)) AS col3,
    SUM(IF(novilho IS TRUE, peso, 0)) AS col4,
    COUNT(*) AS col5,
    SUM(peso) AS col6
FROM bois
WHERE genero = 'F'
GROUP BY d_comp, fk_frnc
```

So the full query would then be -

```sql
SELECT 
    b.d_comp,
    b.fk_frnc,
    CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(b.d_comp, "%d/%m/%Y"), " - ", f.nome) AS alias,
    FORMAT(SUM(b.vlr), 2, 'de_DE') AS vlr,
    
    /* ACRÉSCIMO DE SOMAS, CASO TOTAL POR LOTE ESTEJA HABILITADO */
    CONCAT(
        '<span class="fw-bldr">Fêmeas</span>:<br>Quantidade | Peso<br>Adultas:', /* QTD */ b2.col1, ' | ', /* PESO */ b2.col2,
        '<br>Novilhas: ', b2.col3, ' | ', b2.col4,
        '<br>Total: ', b2.col5, ' | ', b2.col6
    ) AS total_lote
FROM bois AS b
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT
        d_comp,
        fk_frnc,
        SUM(IF(novilho IS FALSE, 1, 0)) AS col1,
        SUM(IF(novilho IS FALSE, peso, 0)) AS col2,
        SUM(IF(novilho IS TRUE, 1, 0)) AS col3,
        SUM(IF(novilho IS TRUE, peso, 0)) AS col4,
        COUNT(*) AS col5,
        SUM(peso) AS col6
    FROM bois
    WHERE genero = 'F'
    GROUP BY d_comp, fk_frnc

) b2 ON b2.d_comp = b.d_comp AND b2.fk_frnc = b.fk_frnc
INNER JOIN fornecedores AS f
    ON b.fk_frnc = f.id    
GROUP BY b.d_comp, b.fk_frnc
```

You can probably combine the inner and outer queries by adding the condition in the where clause to the condition used in the aggregate functions, but we cannot be sure as you have not included any supporting information, particularly the relationship between `fornecedores` AND `bois`, in your question.

```sql
SELECT
    b.d_comp,
    b.fk_frnc,
    CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(b.d_comp, "%d/%m/%Y"), " - ", f.nome) AS alias,
    FORMAT(SUM(b.vlr), 2, 'de_DE') AS vlr,
    
    /* ACRÉSCIMO DE SOMAS, CASO TOTAL POR LOTE ESTEJA HABILITADO */
    CONCAT(
        '<span class="fw-bldr">Fêmeas</span>:<br>Quantidade | Peso<br>Adultas:',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F' AND b.novilho IS FALSE, 1, 0)),
        ' | ',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F' AND b.novilho IS FALSE, b.peso, 0)),
        '<br>Novilhas: ',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F' AND b.novilho IS TRUE, 1, 0)),
        ' | ',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F' AND b.novilho IS TRUE, b.peso, 0)),
        '<br>Total: ',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F', 1, 0)),
        ' | ',
        SUM(IF(b.genero = 'F', b.peso, 0))
    ) AS total_lote
FROM bois b
INNER JOIN fornecedores f
    ON b.fk_frnc = f.id    
GROUP BY b.d_comp, b.fk_frnc
```

I cannot test this or provide a fiddle as you have not included any sample data or the expected output.

P.S. You really should do away with the concatenation and do this in your client application.